# How do I figure out what is changing the userWorkstations attribute in Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, audit, debugging, attributes

I just took over the IT for a medium sized business with a three domain controllers (2003/2008 Standard) and whenever I create a new user, after some time the user account cannot log into most machines on the network.  I have traced this back to the "Log On To..." area becoming populated with a small list of machines.  Even when I set the option to all computers, this list comes back after some time.

I started hunting for vbs and ps1 scripts with the word "workstations" in them on all domain controllers to see if there is some kind of script to blame, but I have thus far come up empty handed.  Is there a known software suite that can cause this (Microsoft Forefront, etc)?

How can I figure out what is causing this list to change?

**Edit**

I turned on auditing at tonyr roth's suggestion, and now I see that the SYSTEM account of one of the domain controllers is periodically writing to the userWorkstations attribute.  Does the system account imply some sort of service or scheduled task?

**Edit**

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/File_Servers/Active_Directory/Q_24106718.html

Appears to have my solution, EBS licensing.

**Edit**

Microsoft EBS is discontinued, and if you bought it you can get the components for free between June 30 2010 and December 31 2010.

ht tp://www.microsoft.com/ebs/en/us/offers.aspx

Answer (score 1):

turn on auditing of ad events!

Comment: There is no audit policy called "AD Events".  I have added a group policy object to my domain controllers to audit Directory Service Access.  Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at **Group Policy Inheritance** and "**Resultant Set of Policies**"

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758010%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: I have run through the group policy modeling and results wizards and I see no scripts or anything that might affect AD.  Thanks though!